# What function can I use to limit my y-axis in a geom_bar plot?

Tags: r

I am new to R and making a very simple histogram, however the range of my y-axis is too large and greatly limits visibility of the graph. I have tried using ylim however I get the error
"Error in discrete_scale(c("x", "xmin", "xmax", "xend"), "position_d",  :
unused argument (ylim = c(0, 75))"

Here is the code used to make the histogram:

```
recipes %>%
mutate(ingredient = fct_infreq(ingredient)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = ingredient)) +
geom_bar() +
scale_x_discrete(labels = NULL)
```

Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you seem to have a wrong sintax in ylim. Try with:

```
recipes %>%
mutate(ingredient = fct_infreq(ingredient)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = ingredient)) +
geom_bar() +
scale_x_discrete(labels = NULL) +
ylim(0, 75)
```